# Run "aapt.exe" on phone directly?

Tags: java, android, aapt, resource-file

I want to create the packaged resource file programmatically and (that's the question) directly in a running app on the android phone. Is there a way to execute "aapt.exe" on the phone or is there another way of creating the resource._rsc file from a java library?

thx for answering!

Comment: you can't run any *.exe on an android device. What is a resource._rsc?

Comment: @see: http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/

Answer (score 1):

Android is a Linux-based OS, while .exe files are Microsoft Windows executables. You can't execute an .exe in Linux, at least not without the help of emulation software.

Comment: Okay, but how does AIDE makes this work? Is there a pure java solution to package the resources?

Comment: They may have written their own resource compiler, ported an existing one to Java and included it into their application, or went some other way. You could try contacting AIDE authors and asking them.